# How can I add the geometry of a geodataframe to a list that's the output of a specific function?

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm running a the function maxp_greedy() of pygeoda library. This function creates clusters from a given data values, this values came from a geodataframe.
The problem is that the mentioned function ouputs the generated clusters but without the geometry of the points used by the function to create the clusters.

This is the code I'm running:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import pygeoda

gpd_table=gpd.read_file(r'...\test.shp')
gda_table = pygeoda.open(gpd_table)

data = gda_table[["id", "p"]]
bound_vals=gda_table["p"]
min_bound=81351.2 

rook_w = pygeoda.rook_weights(gda_table)

maxp_clusters = pygeoda.maxp_greedy(rook_w, data, bound_vals, min_bound ,iterations=99)
```

And the output is a dictionary like this:

```
{'Total sum of squares': 748.0000000000002, 'Within-cluster sum of squares': (222.89587311366276, 3.4016659370682865), 'Total within-cluster sum of squares': 521.7024609492692, 'The ratio of between to total sum of squares': 0.697463183087258, 'Clusters': (3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 
4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 5)}
```

I'm expecting to get a dataframe like this:

```
cluster_id geometry
3          POINT (259507.915 6273745.203)
3          POINT (259485.784 6273772.670)
1          POINT (259141.205 6273775.395) 
3          POINT (259940.746 6275295.453)
3          POINT (259913.650 6275277.372)
3          POINT (259322.650 6273754.954)
2          POINT (259141.205 6273775.395)
3          POINT (259507.915 6273745.203)
...
4          POINT (259913.650 6275277.372)
4          POINT (259507.915 6273745.203)
```

Considering that each of this values on cluster_id corresponds to a point in gpd_table variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you extract the geometries by:

`geom_list = list(gda_table['geometry'])`

And then create a new gdf:

`gdf_clusters = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'cluster_id': maxp_clusters['Clusters'], 'geometry': geom_list})`

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed. Where can I found docum about the format that the list(gda_table['geometry']) output? I want to know what this means: <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000002DBDB6B8278>

Comment: You're welcome. The geometry objects are from module `shapely.geometry`, you can read more about those here: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/geometry.html